# C++ Templates polymorphism used togheter

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I need to define a GUI for the **Camera** class where I have different types of camera.
So to do this I really want to use polymorphism because make sense to use one interface **Camera** for different implementations (**Camera1** , **Camera2**). The problem is that different implementations require different type of **BufferCalculations** that uses template, so I can't use `Camera* camera;` but I need to use something like that `Camera<unsigned char>* camera;`,

Is there any way I can use polymorphism inside the **CameraGui** class even though I have templates in the **BufferCalculations** class?

```cpp
template <typename T> class BufferCalculation {...}
template <typename T> class Camera { BufferCalculation<T> bufferCalculation; }
class Camera1 : public Camera<unsigned char> {}
class Camera2 : public Camera<unsigned short> {}
class CameraGui { Camera* camera; }
```

Comment: `BufferCalculations ` is a member of `Camera`, so what's stopping you exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do in `CameraGui`. If it does not depend on the template parameter type of `Camera`, you could do something like the following:

```
class BasicCamera {...};
template <typename T> class BufferCalculation {...}
template <typename T> class Camera : public BasicCamera { BufferCalculation<T> bufferCalculation; }
class Camera1 : public Camera<unsigned char> {}
class Camera2 : public Camera<unsigned short> {}
class CameraGui { BasicCamera* camera; }
```

If the operations in `CameraGui` depend on the type, you can either make it itself a template class, or make the operations take/return a hierarchy of objects deriving from a non-template type as well.